# mongodb $maxScan didn't equals limit

Tags: mongodb

This is my first question on stack overflow, I am so happy and await your answers. My question is:
   When I use MongoDB Query Selectors, I want limit results. But `$maxScan` is not work as I want.

**---------This is What I want result.**

```
db.post.find({query:{status:"publish"},$orderby:{date:-1}},{status:1,name:1,date:1,$slice:2}).limit(3)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519262580cf21fb1647fb765"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-14T16:12:08.600Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "关于多说" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519254ad0cf2f064f6ecef82"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-14T15:13:49.017Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "回顾<蜗居>的100句经典台词" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519254690cf2f064f6ecef81"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-14T15:12:41.462Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "女人脱光了是什么" }
```

**-----------This is the results I use  $maxScan**

```
db.post.find({query:{status:"publish"},$maxScan:3,$orderby:{date:-1}},{status:1,name:1,date:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518e6c690cf21a363df2956e"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-11T16:06:01.341Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "淘宝新店,充值任务" }
```

I find may be the $maxScan didn't like limit(). it first limit the collection data and then execute the query! but this is not I want. Is anything i wrong? please help.Thanks

**--------------All results**

```
db.post.find({query:{},$orderby:{date:-1}},{status:1,name:1,date:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519262580cf21fb1647fb765"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-14T16:12:08.600Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "关于多说" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519254ad0cf2f064f6ecef82"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-14T15:13:49.017Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "回顾<蜗居>的100句经典台词" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519254690cf2f064f6ecef81"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-14T15:12:41.462Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "女人脱光了是什么" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518ee61a0cf22bd326d60215"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-12T00:45:14.295Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "JSTL日期格式化用法(转载)" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518e6c690cf21a363df2956e"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-11T16:06:01.341Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "淘宝新店,充值任务" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518e21c90cf21a363df2956d"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-11T10:47:37.803Z"), "status" : "draft", "name" : "一夜没睡" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518df75d0cf21a363df2956c"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-11T07:46:37.726Z"), "status" : "draft", "name" : "飞娥入侵" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518d80630cf21a363df2956b"), "date" : ISODate("2013-05-10T23:18:59.323Z"), "status" : "publish", "name" : "Java的日期格式化常用方法" }
```

Comment: Dude, format your code, highlight it and press CTRL+K, edit: Did it for you, just approve

Comment: Are you using Node.js, or just mongo its self

Comment: thanks your reply, I just use mongo its self

Answer (score 1):

To return only the top results, you should use [`limit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit), which will *limit the amount of results returned from the cursor*. This is commonly used with [`skip()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) to paginate the results.

It's not explained very clearly in the docs, but [`$maxScan`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/maxScan/#op._S_maxScan) as the name suggests *limits the number of documents the query will examine*. Presumably your query is examining some documents which don't meet the criteria (with `status != publish`) and then discarding them.

Do you have an index on `status`? It's possible that could help the query return the results you want while scanning fewer documents, but I still think `limit()` is what you want.

Comment: The $maxScan will only ever scan documents which fit the criteria, which his example does, it just means it will scan 3 documents and then class the race complete

Comment: I known limit() can work. But I use spring. how can I code it?
i want use some  query Operators.

Comment: @Kaibb there is a `$limit` query operator

Comment: @Sammaye How could mongo know whether a document fits the criteria before it actually scans it? Unless there's an index, it has no way of knowing. I also don't see a `$limit` operator.

Comment: @noa is right! where is the $limit, Could you please provide the link?